# I want to store the values entered in datagridview into SQL Server

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to store the values entered in datagridview into SQL Server, but if second row is null its showing object reference not set to instance of an object

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       int i = 0;
       foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
       //{

       {
           string keyword = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
           string name = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
           string comm = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
           string retur = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
           string message = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
           i = pbl.fsave(keyword, name, comm, retur, message);
       }
           //string insert_sql = "INSERT INTO TblProtocolDetails(KeyWord,Command,Return)VALUES('" + keyword + "','" + comm + "','" + retur + "')";

       //}
   }
```

Comment: what is the problem??

Comment: try this                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289894/saving-data-from-datagridview-to-sql-server-database?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //For Trusted connection
        string cnStr = "Data Source=[Your SQL Server Name];Initial Catalog=[Your Database Name];Integrated Security=True";

        var cn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(cnStr);
        var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();

        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TblProtocolDetails(KeyWord,Command,Return)VALUES(@keyword,@comm,@retur)";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("(@keyword", ""));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("(@comm", ""));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("(@retur", ""));

            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    //Uncomment if only for new rows
                    //if (!row.IsNewRow)
                    //{
                        string keyword = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                        string name = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                        string comm = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                        string retur = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                        string message = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();

                        cmd.Parameters[0].Value = keyword;
                        cmd.Parameters[1].Value = comm;
                        cmd.Parameters[2].Value = retur;

                        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                        {//Insert Successful!
                            //DO SOMETHING
                        }
                        else
                        {//Insert failed.
                            //DO SOMETHING
                        }

                        //i = pbl.fsave(keyword, name, comm, retur, message);
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        cmd.Dispose();
        if (cn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            cn.Close();

        cn.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the isnewrow property and the row type. (It could be header row, footer etc.)